# Cardano Blockchain backup

Tags: cardano-node, ledger

I wanted to make a backup of the Cardano DB for a faster restoration in the future.

Should I make a backup of all the folder DB or just the folder ledger ?

and when I need to restore should I restore the full DB folder or only some part of it?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You should make a backup of the entire `db` folder as the majority of the data is inside the `immutable` folder.

For restoring, just copy all the content of the folder in the new node.